# Error while installing kivy

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy

I am trying to install kivy on my to get started with a project but when i do

`pip install kivy`

it installs for a while and throw me this error

```
c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r0fj_elc\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h':
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for kivy
```

and ends up with

```
c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r0fj_elc\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scraptesting\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-r0fj_elc\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wk6wljj6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scraptesting\include\site\python3.5\kivy" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-r0fj_elc\kivy\

(scrapTesting) D:\PycharmProjects\Environments\scrapTesting\splash_testing>
```

any help , and also i'm following kivy documentations for [installlation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing [wheel](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-nightly-win-dist)

It doesn't work on 3.5 or above as the documents say, so you have to do an appropriate installation of the `.whl` from the list and then on the terminal do,

`pip install YourPackage.whl`